# async-await in typescript - Not waiting for the awaited function to be executed completely

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have the following scenario in a typescript file:

```
async function a() : Promise<void> {
  try {
    var result = await b(); 
    console.log('result=' + result);
  } catch(err){

  } finally {
    console.log('fin');
  }
}

async function b() : Promise<number> {
    let x: number = 1;
    console.log('start');
    // A long time taking http call - tried making the http request, both with or without await, but no change in result.
    // x got modified to 2 as a result of above call.
    console.log('x=' + x);
    return x;
}
a();
```

All this happening in a single file, with almost above skeleton, my concern here is that for the above code, I am expecting output to be `start x=2 result=2 fin`.
But the output I am getting is `start result=undefined fin x=2`.

From the output, it seems like the function b starts executing, but since it's taking time, the next lines are executed even if I have await. Also, x=2 in the print confirms that the http call is successful. Thus, I can't put any logic in function a based on the output of b, which I intend to do.

My tsconfig has following:

```
"target": "es2015",
"module": "commonjs",
"lib": ["es5","es2015"]
```

Could someone please help me with this? Thanks

Comment: It really depends how you "make" the http request. Adding `async` only does two things: The function returns a promise and you can use `await` inside the function. It's still on you to properly `await` internal async function calls. `await` only works as expected if the value is a promise.

Comment: @FelixKling It's a simple https request like `const req = await https.request(options, (res) => { …}; req.write(data); req.end();`

Comment: If the API accepts a callback it probably does not return  a promise.

Comment: The API is in C#, and it returns Task<> type, which is equivalent to returning a promise. I guess. Thanks btw.

Comment: No I mean that `https.request` accepts a callback. In that case it does not return a promise, so `await https.request(...)` won’t actually “wait” until the request completed. You can create a wrapper function that actually returns a promise for the request.

Comment: docs: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback to use await you need a promise to await on. the docs don't refer to promises. `To get the response, add a listener for 'response' to the request object. 'response' will be emitted from the request object when the response headers have been received. The 'response' event is executed with one argument which is an instance of http.IncomingMessage.` Wrap it in a promise and resolve it that event.